# setDownloadBehavior in watir for headless chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir

The headless mode in chrome doesn't support file download. There are various solutions proposed under [issue here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481).

Below solution for selenium is from that page, Comment 78.

```
def enable_chrome_headless_downloads(driver, directory)
  bridge = driver.send(:bridge)
  path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
  path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id
  bridge.http.call(:post, path, {
  "cmd" => "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
  "params" => {
    "behavior" => "allow",
    "downloadPath" => directory,
  }
})
end
```

But this doesn't work for watir. How to implement the same solution while using watir.

Comment: facing the same issue, any updates ? have solved this problem ?

Comment: headless-chrome still has this issue. Mine was a csv download , i "resolved" it by printing the csv instead of download if requested from headless-chrome.